# Material-UI Checkbox is not reset while using react-hook-form reset function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using

`"react-hook-form": "7.9.0",`

And

`"@material-ui/core": "4.11.4",`.

I'm trying to reset some checkbox manually by clicking on regular button and using the `reset` ([react-hook-form reset](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset)) method of `react-hook-form`.

For some reason I can see in react dev tools that the "checked" prop is changing to false but the SwitchBase (v icon) is still on.

You can see example: [Over here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-flower-90gfd?file=/src/App.js)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6):

The MUI `<Checkbox />` component has a slighty different interface for setting a `value`. The RHF value has to be set with `checked` prop.

One important note: you have to set the value with `checked={!!value}` to avoid a warning about changing a component from uncontrolled to controlled in case that your `defaultValue` for `someCheckbox` is initially `undefined`.

```js
export const Checkbox = ({
  name,
  label,
  control,
  labelPlacement,
  disabled,
  className
}) => {
  return (
    <FormControlLabel
      label={label}
      disabled={disabled}
      labelPlacement={labelPlacement}
      className={className}
      control={
        <Controller
          name={name}
          control={control}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field: { value, ...field } }) => (
            <MuiCheckbox
              {...field}
              checked={!!value}
            />
          )}
        />
      }
    />
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Issue with reseting Material UI Checkbox using react-hook-form (forked)]

Answer (score 4):

The `controller` hook uses `value` (which is true/false) and not `checked` (which is what `Checkbox` of Material-UI expects) in order to set the check-status of the checkbox.

In order to fix your issue you can take the `value` from the `field` (inside the render property of the Controller) and set it to the `checked` property of the `Checkbox`:

```
  control={
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      rules={{ required: true }}
      render={({ field }) => <MuiCheckbox {...field} checked={field['value'] ?? false} /> }
    />
  }
```